# Unable to access Remote MySQL

Tags: cpanel, remote-access

I have been having a remote connection problem with the database in my domain afrikinu.com. I intend to use the database as a source of data for a mobile app.

I have tried using the IP `198.23.61.43` (which I found added as an Access Host in Remote MySQL) in the database configuration settings as the host, to no avail:

```
<?php
$host = "198.23.61.43";
$mysql_username = "afrikinu_george";
$mysql_pwd = "***";
$db_name = "afrikinu_myheart_ke";
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $mysql_username, $mysql_pwd, $db_name);
?>
```

I have also tried using the Shared IP Address `170.10.161.21` from the Server Information in both Remote MySQL and the configuration settings but it didn't work as well.

I noticed that the Home Directory in cPanel Main was set to `/home1/afrikinu` but the connection, by default, tries to access `/home/afrikinu` as seen in the error log, and think this might be the problem.

[cPanel Main](http://www.afrikinu.com/cpanel_main.jpg)

[error log](http://www.afrikinu.com/error_log.jpg)

If this is the problem, how do I resolve it? If it isn't, then what might be the problem?

I have tried very many proposed solutions including contacting my host providers concerning the remote connection issue but all attempts have ended up futile.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: First you have to ask about the port forwarding and is it available remote access from your server?

Comment: how do I do that??

Comment: links are broken, please upload the picture and copy/paste the error message.

Comment: It's fine Gilles. I already resolved the issue (the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you should never use a `$` in your user password :)) That was the issue. Thanks for the response.